# Listings and continuation captions

Tags: captions, listings

In my document (KOMA script article) I use the `listings` package for code listings and the `caption` package for additional control over captions.

My problem is that some listings flow over multiple pages. When this occurs I would like to have something like "Listing n, continued", or something to that effect at the start of each additional page --- so a contination caption.

I know the captions package supports breaking up captions and doing the "continued" stuff, but am unsure how to get the listings package on board. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't find a ready-to-use feature here's an approach using the header: right before the long listing you could use \markboth to add the listings name to the header entry. No matter how long the (perhaps external) file is, the header would show the name, perhaps in addition to the section name.

If you like this approach I could create an example.

Comment: This sounds great. A brief example would be appreciated. Do you need to manually 'unmarkboth' after the listing?